# Broken dependencies in Fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, ros-package-path, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I installed ros-fuerte-desktop-full beta yesterday using this [manual](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu). I'm using Ubuntu 11.10. Everything seems to be good, but when I try to compile my old project, I receive next [messages](http://pastebin.com/USjYWUQY).

manifest.xml contains next:

```
<package>
  <description brief="RobotVision">

     RobotVision

  </description>
  <author>crady</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
  <url>http://ros.org/wiki/RobotVision</url>
  <depend package="pcl"/>
  <depend package="pcl_ros"/>
  <depend package="roscpp"/>
  <depend package="sensor_msgs"/>
  <depend package="vosch"/>
</package>
```

What is wrong? I'm missing something? Project created and works on electric.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31270/broken-dependencies-in-fuerte/) by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 546 on 2012-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-05**:
What is your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and other ROS environment settings?  'env | grep ROS'

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-05**:
Please answer Tully's question about ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2012-04-05**:
$ env | grep ROS

ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/crady/ros:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/common-lisp/ros

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

ROS_DISTRO=fuerte

ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/fuerte/etc/ros

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-06**:
Did appending ":/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros" to the end of your $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH work?

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2012-04-07**:
Seems that this helps. Now it complains on really missing package, not "virtually". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you need the PCL library itself, now separately installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pcl
```

You can use the new `rosdep` script to make sure you install everything:

```
$ rosdep install RobotVision
```

UPDATE: my `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` contains all this:

```
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2012-04-05**:
I received next

rosdep install RobotVision
All required rosdeps installed successfully

and from apt-get install

ros-fuerte-pcl is already the newest version.
ros-fuerte-pcl set to manually installed.

Everything seems to be good, but does not compile.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-05**:
That sounds like a new question. Please ask it separately with error messages, etc.

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2012-04-05**:
I didn't understand you, what about question?

rosdep and apt-get install works fine, they say that all dependencies for my project (like pcl) already installed (and it's true - I can see libs and headers in /opt/fuerte). But I still have error with them from my first post.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks and /opt/ros/fuerte/share in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH like this:

```
/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-10**:
Mine also contains /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros ($ROS_ROOT). Not sure what is adding that. Is it unnecessary?